# H2O Webserver - Multiple domains - Is possible ? Or current version is only for one domain?

Tags: webserver, domain, virtual-host

I'm testing h2o server : (some urls )

https://github.com/h2o/h2o/wiki

https://calomel.org/h2o.html

All works fine with only one domain but when I try to load multiple domains I can't load different paths for these domains:

This is a simple settings ( I hide some config lines to question be clear )  :

```
hosts:
  "domain_01.com": 
     listen: PORT
     paths:
       "/":
         file.dir: /path_01

  "domain_02.com":
     listen: PORT
     paths:
       "/":
         file.dir: /path_02
```

The problem is when I try to load domain_01.com/file.htm is always loaded the first path (path_01).

What I'm doing wrong ? Is posible multiple domains with h2o server ?